# async draw UILabel crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uilabel

I try to draw UILabel content in async thread,and meet some crash,`Crashed: async_display.queue :: NSOperation 0x17444b5e0 (QOS: USER_INTERACTIVE)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000058`, below is sample code:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [NSLayoutManager new];
    layoutManager.usesFontLeading = NO;
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:text];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:contentSize];
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0;
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    [layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:textContainer];
    CGPoint glyphsPosition = CGPointZero;
    CGRect textBounds = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contentSize, NO, 0.0);

    NSRange glyphRange = [layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];
    [layoutManager drawBackgroundForGlyphRange:glyphRange atPoint:glyphsPosition];
    [layoutManager drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:glyphRange atPoint:glyphsPosition];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  });
}
```

crash at the line `[layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:textContainer];`, and the crash info:

```
0  UIFoundation                   0x187486768 -[NSATSLineFragment getTypographicLineHeight:baselineOffset:leading:] + 116
1  UIFoundation                   0x18747d1e0 -[NSATSTypesetter _layoutLineFragmentStartingWithGlyphAtIndex:characterIndex:atPoint:renderingContext:] + 2392
2  UIFoundation                   0x18747e758 -[NSATSTypesetter layoutParagraphAtPoint:] + 160
3  UIFoundation                   0x1874d4b34 -[NSTypesetter _layoutGlyphsInLayoutManager:startingAtGlyphIndex:maxNumberOfLineFragments:maxCharacterIndex:nextGlyphIndex:nextCharacterIndex:] + 2948
4  UIFoundation                   0x1874d5cd8 -[NSTypesetter layoutCharactersInRange:forLayoutManager:maximumNumberOfLineFragments:] + 244
5  UIFoundation                   0x18747f1b8 -[NSATSTypesetter layoutCharactersInRange:forLayoutManager:maximumNumberOfLineFragments:] + 448
6  UIFoundation                   0x18746b2ec -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _fillLayoutHoleForCharacterRange:desiredNumberOfLines:isSoft:] + 1116
7  UIFoundation                   0x18746cde0 -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _fillLayoutHoleAtIndex:desiredNumberOfLines:] + 196
8  UIFoundation                   0x187479a94 _NSFastFillAllLayoutHolesUpToEndOfContainerForGlyphIndex + 1252
9  UIFoundation                   0x1874a2100 -[NSLayoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:] + 380
10 project                          0x10056d384 __36-[AsyncDisplayLabel displayBlock]_block_invoke (ESPAsyncDisplayLabel.m:112)
11 project                          0x10056db4c __29-[AsyncLayer asyncDisplay]_block_invoke.73 (ESPAsyncLayer.m:93)
```

I try to use pthread_mutex_t to lock the NSTextKit init but alway meet the crash...

Comment: You must perform UI operations on the main queue

Comment: NSTextKit is threadSafe, AsyncDisplayKit also use it in other thread~ @Paulw11

Comment: What is the exception message you are getting.  Which line in your code did it crash on.  You have only shown part of the stack trace.

Comment: @Paulw11 crash at `[layoutManager ensureLayoutForTextContainer:textContainer];`

Comment: And the exception message is...?

Comment: @Paulw11 `Crashed: async_display.queue :: NSOperation 0x17444b5e0 (QOS: USER_INTERACTIVE)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000058`

Comment: Still, you need to do UI operations on the main queue. Whether your code is threadSafe or not, that is irrelevant.